# EdX API to get a Course List

Tags: api, edx

It seems to be possible for anyone to get a list from all edx courses. unfortunately the available documents are looking incomplete.

Is there any way to obtain a course list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you talking about the list of courses running on edx.org? For that, you would need an OAuth key to access that API endpoint, and I don't believe that edx.org currently gives out OAuth keys. That API endpoint is currently intended for internal use only.

If you want to run your own Open edX installation, then you'll be able to access this API endpoint from your own instance, and it will return information about the courses you have running on your own installation.

But you do have an other option, you can use RSS feed from [www.edx.org](https://www.edx.org)

https://www.edx.org/api/v2/report/course-feed/rss

i found this [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/edx-code/edx$20api/edx-code/g_ciCTwcLwM/yEHPD5zkxDAJ)

i hope this helps !

Answer (score 2):

The docs do not give the root URI to run your api queries against. Anyone can host an instance of the edX platform, hence the root URI can change. Here is a fully qualified URL for the edX course API:

https://courses.edx.org/api/courses/v1/courses/

Visiting this URL will show the results that an anonymous user would see.

Answer (score 0):

After some soulfull searching i found one of the most pretty API docs i have ever seen. all that you need to know about pulling course content.

https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/course-catalog-api-guide/latest/course-catalog-api-guide.pdf

Answer (score -1):

Looks like they have one now!

I too was looking for an EdX api that would hopefully include access to a current courses catalogue and also include all course descriptions.

Not sure when it was released but this looks like a good direction for me - http://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/edx-platform-api/en/latest/courses/overview.html

Hope this is helpful.